# How to remove first n lines or last n lines from .txt file with SWI Prolog?

Tags: stream, prolog

I'm reading a textfile via SWI Prolog and want to skip the first n lines of this textfile and the last m ones. How is this possible?

Here is how I read my file:

```
read_and_print_file(File):-
    open(File, read, Stream),
    skip('skip_apart_from_here'), # <- ?
    repeat,
    (   at_end_of_stream(Stream)
            -> !
            ; get_char(Stream, Char),
            write(Char),
            fail
    ),
    close(Stream).
```

Comment: Right now, you are not storing larger chunks of the stream, but you directly write single characters. If you want to skip the *last* m lines, I think there will be no way around storing at least m lines, because you have to look ahead m lines...

Comment: I guess I would make it simple - just read in all lines, remove the first n and last m ones and then start the writing. Is that an option for you or are you dealing with large files and thus want to minimize intermediate storage?